# Android app disappears sometimes from apps screen

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, app-launcher

My android app appears and disappears on app screen indeliberately.

I couldn't find why this problem happens.

- Is the problem happening because my app manifest ?
- Is the problem related to the android version ?

etc..

### Spec

*Device manufacturer* : Samsung

*Device model*        : SM-T311

*Android version*     : 4.4.2

### How it happens

- I install my app from email
- I open my app and use it
- I press home
  button
- I press apps button

I couldn't see my app

### How I solve this

- I again press home button
- I again press apps
- I see my app

### Note

I don't see this problem with any other devices

Any help is appreciated !